# Using reactive variable inside dplyr verb with pooling

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, pool

I have some input and have reactive value bind to them update when user click an action button. I use `dplyr` with `pool` to retrieve data from an external database.

Below is my `working` code to update a reactive data frame:

```
  date_from <- eventReactive(input$btn_update, {
    return(format(input$date_time[1], "%Y-%m-%d"))
  })

  date_to <- eventReactive(input$btn_update, {
    return(format(input$date_time[2], "%Y-%m-%d"))
  })

  daily_active_users <- eventReactive(input$btn_update, {
    from <- date_from()
    to <- date_to()
    return(collect(
      src_pool(pool_instance) %>% tbl("daily_active_user") %>%
        filter(time >= from, time <= to) %>%
        arrange(time) %>%
        mutate(net_change = dau - lag(dau)) %>%
        mutate(net_change = if_else(is.na(net_change), 0, net_change))
    ))
  })
```

Since I have many reactive data frame depends on date_from, and date_to, I want to achieve something like (to reduce code duplication):

```
  daily_active_users <- eventReactive(input$btn_update, {
    return(collect(
      src_pool(pool_instance) %>% tbl("daily_active_user") %>%
        filter(time >= date_from(), time <= date_to()) %>%
        arrange(time) %>%
        mutate(net_change = dau - lag(dau)) %>%
        mutate(net_change = if_else(is.na(net_change), 0, net_change))
    ))
  })
```

But when running, it raise the error like:

`RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  function date_from() does not exist
LINE 6: WHERE (("time" >= DATE_FROM()) AND ("time" <= DATE_TO()))) "...
                          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
)`

Is there any better solution for my case?

Kind regards.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? `dplyr` seems to be treating `date_from()` as a built in function and is passing it along with out evaluating. This makes sense most of the time. You are really better off sticking to your above code block which eliminates that ambiguity. You could use the standard-evaluation version `filter_()` to force evaluation but that won't be very pretty.

Comment: I use PostgreSQL as the backend db.
Changing `filter` to `filter_` and also change the name of reactive variable to `date_begin` and `date_end` also raise the error: 

`comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types`

Actually I have many reactive data frame so duplicated code could be a pain.